# Clearing Class Foo with new(pFoo) Foo()

Tags: c++

I'm going to be honest. I'm feeling a bit under the weather so this might be a stupid question. If so yell at me and I'll delete it. Having issues with a program not clearing some data every once and a while and causing a mismatch with some dirty bits. Popular opinion is that we have a race condition. When i was looking at some of the old code however i noticed that the Fifo Array class has a bit of unique way of clearing itself. I've abstracted what i think are the relevant bits as follows.

File Foo.hpp

```
template<class T, unsigned N, intrptr_t nilVal>
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo();
    protected:    
        data[N+1]
        size;
}
inline Foo<T, N, nilVal>::Foo(): nextIn(0), Size, nextOut(0) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i <= N; ++i){
        data[i] = (T)nilVal;
    }
}
```

File Bar.hpp

```
#include "Foo.hpp"

class Bar{
    public: 
        Bar() : fizz() {}
        ~Bar() {}

        static void Clear(Bar* pBar);
    private:
        Foo<void*, CAPACITY, 0U> fizz;
```

File Bar.cpp

```
#include "Bar.hpp"

void Bar::Clear(Bar *pBar){
    Lock lock;
    CRITICAL_REGION(lock){
        new(pBar) Bar();
    }
}
```

File Logic.cpp

```
#include "Bar.hpp"

logic(){
    Bar* bar = Woof::GetBar();
    bar->Clear(bar)
    ...
}
```

This code has been in there for years, and it appears to be working. Now i've done a bit of googling and gotten a bit suspicious. When Bar::Clear() is called in logic() if i were to check then check every location in data[], will data[] actually be empty? If so i would appreciate it if someone could elaborate on why this works, whereas new(this) is evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is legal-ish and it will depend on what `T` is for whether or not this is legal. Doing

```
new(pBar) Bar();
```

is going to end the lifetime of the object `pBar` points to and puts a new object in its place.  That means `fizz` will look like it did when you created the `Bar` instance.

[[basic.life]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.life#5)

> A program may end the lifetime of any object by reusing the storage which the object occupies or by explicitly calling the destructor for an object of a class type. For an object of a class type, the program is not required to call the destructor explicitly before the storage which the object occupies is reused or released; however, if there is no explicit call to the destructor or if a delete-expression is not used to release the storage, the destructor is not implicitly called and any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined behavior.

Tells us this is okay, as long as `Bar`'s destructor has no observable side effects.  So if `T` was an `int` (`void*` in this case) then there is nothing observe in it being destroyed and the code is fine.  If `T` was a `std::vector` though, then there is an issue.  `std::vector`'s destructor has side effects (desroys the elements, returns allocated memory) so the code would have undefined behavior.

Comment: It's not ok if it is a race condition as the question states.  You can safely have potentially overlapping access to an object from multiple threads only if all of them are purely reading... the lock doesn't appear to do any good because each user has an independently lock, there is never contention or blocking on a shared lock, so no synchronization between threads takes place.

Comment: In this actual code the lock is a bit more complicated than my abstraction makes it out to be.You can assume that the critical region is the only thread capable of running on the machine while it is active.

Comment: In the actual code only one thread has permission to modify or read the Data also. The issue we are observing is a mismatch between the actual stored data, and a reference copy of the data kept in another location on the same hardware. Specifically after a switchover we tell the actual data to go through and clear whatever it finds in it's area. Whenever it finds something it reports to the reference copy that it has stuff it needs to clear, and the reference copy is telling us that some of the stuff we are clearing doesnt exist.